# Trying to make items in a div spread between evenly

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

i'm currently trying to make the items in the container div spread evenly on one line. The result I would like is the following:

[image]

Currently I can't seem to figure out how to make the items go on the same line and spread evenly between the space that is available?

this is what I currently have:

[image]

The first 2 pieces of text should go on the left, and then the next 2 have to go in the middle ish. but spread evenly between each other should be fine aswell! I tried using justify-content: space-between but I can't seem to get it to work.

My code currently:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-text">
      <span class="function-text-bold">{{ functionBold }}</span>
      <span class="function-text">{{ functionDescription }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-text">
      <span class="amount-text">Aantal toegelaten studenten per sessie</span>
      <div class="click-amount">
        <button><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-12v-2h12v2z"/></svg></button>
        <span class="function-text">{{ amountPerSession }}</span>
        <button><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z"/></svg></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button>Stel je tijdslot in</button>
    <!-- Rounded switch -->
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CompanyJobOfferList",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: {
    functionBold: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    functionDescription: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    amountPerSession: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 70px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.click-amount {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
}

.click-amount button{
  border: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

button {
  border: 2px solid var(--accent-color);
}
</style>
```

Comment: use ```width:100%;``` ?

Comment: @frankfurt That does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a table: [Working example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
  <table style="table-layout: auto; width:100%">
    <thead>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50%; padding: 0px 20px">
          <div>
            Functie
          </div>
          <div>
            Functieomschrijving
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:50%; padding: 0px 20px">
          <div>
            Aantal toegelaten stunden per sissie
          </div>
          <div>
            [ - ] 0 [ + ]
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1px; padding: 0px 20px">
          <button style="border: 2px solid black; height: 3rem; width: 10rem">
            Stel je tijdslot in
          </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1px; padding: 0px 20px">
          toggle
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```